# Calculating sales taxes using functions in python

Tags: python

I can't get this program in Python 3.3.5 to run and not sure what I did wrong. The program 
is to ask the user to enter the total sales for the month, then calculate and display the 
the following, the amount of county sale (county sales tax is 2.5percent) and amount of
state sales tax (state sales taxrate is .05) and the total sales tax (county plus state)
I've copied and pasted what I've done so far.

```
# Show individually the 5 purchases amounts, compute the state and county sales
# tax on those combined  purchases and calculate the total of taxes
# and purchases
county_sales_tax =  .025 
state_sales_tax = .05

# Enter the purchase price
def main():
  purchase = float(input('Enter the price of the purchase: '))
  calculate_totals(purchase)

# Calculate the purchase price with the coounty and state sales tax
def calculate_totals(purchase):
  county_sales_tax = purchase * .025 
  state_sales_tax = purchase * .05
  total_sales_tax = county_sales_tax + state_sales_tax
  total_price = purchase + state_sales_tax + county_sales_tax


# display the amount of the purchases, county and state sales
# taxes, combined amount of the both taxes and total sale with taxes
def display_totals(purchase, state_sales_tax, county_sales_tax, total_taxes, total_price):
  print('The purchase price is $, ')
  print('The county_sales_tax is $', \
    format (county_sales_tax, '.2f'))
  print('The state_sales_tax is $', \
    format (state_sales_tax, '.2f'))
  print('The total_sales_tax is $:, ')
  print('The total_price is $:, ')

# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: You "can't get this program to run"? Why not? Does it throw an error? If so, post the full error. As written, your tabs and indentation are wrong, but I don't know if that was just because of copy/pasting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also your functions don't return anything. Also your `display_totals` function is using variables that only exist within the `calculate_totals` function. You need to read a bit about variable scoping.

Comment: Space between `format` and the parameters. Indents (probably just copied wrong.

Comment: Put display_totals() in main

Comment: @ZWiki: The unnecessary spaces are bad style (as is using backslash continuations, especially when you already get a free continuation from an open parens, etc.), but they're not going to break anything.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed up a few things, I'll try to walk through where some of the mistakes were.

```
def calculateStateTax(price):
    state_sales_tax = .05
    return price * state_sales_tax

def calculateCountyTax(price):
    county_sales_tax =  .025
    return price * county_sales_tax

def displayTotals(price):
    print('Original price', price)
    state_tax = calculateStateTax(price)
    print('State tax', state_tax)
    county_tax = calculateCountyTax(price)
    print('County tax', county_tax)
    print('Total', price + state_tax + county_tax)

def main():
    price = float(input('Enter the price of the purchase: '))
    displayTotals(price)
```

1. Indentation is super important in Python! The indentation is used to define the scope of things, note that all the code that is within a defined function is tabbed (or 4 spaces) over
2. In general, you can use functions input parameters and return values to pass things around, instead of declaring global variables.
3. Note that the `displayTotals` function calls the other functions, and gets values out of them via `return`. This means `displayTotals` doesn't need all those parameters to be passed in.
4. It is generally better to only define constants within the scope that they need to exist (e.g. `state_sales_tax` doesn't need to be global).